# How to add data into a table only if it doesnt already exist?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I have thought about using distinct but im not too sure how to do it as a single query for efficiency of code, is there a way? I am basically trying to check if there is already an existing data entry, I am trying to check it with BookingTime. Thanks :)

**This is my SQL query:**

```
   string bookingInfo = "INSERT INTO Booking(BookingDate, BookingTime, CustomerID, EmployeeID, ServiceType, BookingLength) " +
                      "VALUES (@BookingDate, @BookingTime, @CustomerID, @EmployeeID, @ServiceType, @BookingLength) " +
                     "where not exists (SELECT 1 FROM Booking WHERE BookingTime = @BookingTime)";
```

The error I receive: **"Additional information: Query input must contain at least one table or query."**

Comment: What do you want to do if a duplicate is found? Do you want to do nothing or do you want to update the record found with the values in your current insert try?

Comment: At the moment I am thinking if there is a duplicate just display a message to the user and dont add the duplicate to the database.

Comment: But is BookingTime a primary key or unique index of the table?

Comment: At the moment it is a date/time data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to let the database do the checking.

Create a unique index or constraint on the table:

```
create unique index unq_booking_bookingtime on booking(bookingtime);
```

Note: this is based on your query.  It seems unlikely to me that only `bookingtime` defines uniqueness.

The database will then generate an error if it encounters duplicates.  You can prevent the error using `insert ignore` or `insert on duplicate key update` (the latter is the preferred method).

Comment: Thank you, my sql programming is very weak, should I remove the where not exists and replace it with your line of code?

Comment: @JordanCoaten . . . Yes.  You should let the database do the checking -- but note that you will get an error on the insert.  You can avoid that error (most of the time) by using the `where`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string bookingInfo = "INSERT INTO Booking(BookingDate, BookingTime, CustomerID, EmployeeID, ServiceType, BookingLength) " +
                  "SELECT @BookingDate, @BookingTime, @CustomerID, @EmployeeID, @ServiceType, @BookingLength " +
                 " FROM Booking WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE BookingTime = @BookingTime) LIMIT 1 "
```

Try this [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d061)

Comment: I tried this but it creates a loop which keeps adding to my database.

Comment: Now it says there is a syntax error even after I added the semi colon.

Comment: Updated the answer with a SqlFiddle example

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is invalid is invalid in the "INSERT ... VALUES" statement shown.

MySQL does provide an "INSERT ... SELECT ..." form of the INSERT statement (which does not use a VALUES clause). The SELECT statement can have a WHERE clause, but to include a WHERE clause in a SELECT, there has to be a FROM clause. You can use an inline view (aka a derived table) to return a single row, or you could use the builtin Oracle-style dummy table DUAL to return a single row.  (We don't care what columns get returned, we just need one row returned.)

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Booking
( BookingDate
, BookingTime
, CustomerID
, EmployeeID
, ServiceType
, BookingLength
) 
SELECT @BookingDate
     , @BookingTime
     , @CustomerID
     , @EmployeeID
     , @ServiceType
     , @BookingLength
 FROM ( SELECT 1 ) i
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
          FROM Booking b 
         WHERE b.BookingTime = @BookingTime
      )
```

Now the SELECT statement (which can be tested separately from the INSERT) will return either zero or one rows. And whatever row it returns will be passed to the INSERT.

As an alternative to the "NOT EXISTS" predicate, you could use an anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT @BookingDate
     , @BookingTime
     , @CustomerID
     , @EmployeeID
     , @ServiceType
     , @BookingLength
 FROM ( SELECT 1 ) i
 LEFT
 JOIN Booking b
   ON b.BookingTime = @BookingTime
WHERE b.BookingTime IS NULL
```

Comment: "FROM(SELECT 1) i WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  FROM Booking b WHERE b.BookingTime = @BookingTime)";    Im not too sure how to add this in to my program.

Comment: The example SQL INSERT statement in this answer is a *replacement* for the SQL text shown in the question (i.e. the literal string to be assigned to bookingInfo.)